# Send freemarker templated email

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

please help me to fix a problem:

```
       @Service
public class MailSenderServiceImpl implements MailSenderService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailSenderServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    @Autowired
    Configuration freemarkerConfiguration;
@Override
    public void sendTemplatedEmail(String to, String from, String template, Map<String, Object> templatedMimeMessage)
            throws IOException {
        FileTemplateLoader templateLoader = new FileTemplateLoader(new File("src/main/resources"));
        freemarkerConfiguration.setTemplateLoader(templateLoader);
        MimeMessagePreparator preparator;
        try {
            preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

                // Generate a string from the template
                String messageText = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(
                        freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate(template), templatedMimeMessage);

                @Override
                public void prepare(MimeMessage message) throws Exception {
                    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
                    helper.setTo(to);
                    helper.setFrom(from);
                    helper.setText(messageText, true);
                }
            };
            Assert.notNull(javaMailSender, "javaMailSender must not be null");
            this.javaMailSender.send(preparator);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Failed to send email for templated message:" + 
                         "\nFrom:" + from + 
                         "\nTo:" + to + 
                         "\nMessageMap:" + templatedMimeMessage, ex);

        }

    } }
```

Here is an integration test:

```
` @Test
    public void sendTemplatedEmail() throws IOException {

        EmailTemplate template = createEmailTemplateObj("Test subject 111111", "Test body 11111111",
                TemplateType.TENANT_CREATION);

        // Send message using Free Marker template
        Map<String, Object> freeMarkderTemplateMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        freeMarkderTemplateMap.put("subject", template.getSubject());
        freeMarkderTemplateMap.put("body", template.getBody());

        mailSenderService.sendTemplatedEmail("test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com", 
                "email.ftl", freeMarkderTemplateMap);
    }`
```

My test doesn't passed, I get **Template "email.ftl" not found** exception , but it exists under **src/main/resources**. I'm not added

```
<bean id="freeMarkerConfiguration" class="freemarker.template.Configuration" factory-bean="freeMarkerConfigurationFactory" factory-method="createConfiguration" scope="prototype"/>
```

in spring.xml. Suppose it's not the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "src" directory is for the developers tools, not for the running application, so you shouldn't ever have "src" in your source code. Also, you aren't loading `Files` here, but class-loader resources, so, use a `ClassTemplateLoader`, and specify the path relatively to `src/main/resources`. So in your case it would be `new ClassTemplateLoader(SomeClass.class, "/")`, but it's nicer to create a subdirectory like `src/main/resources/com/example/myproject/templates`, in which case the argument will be `"/com/example/myproject/templates"`.

Another thing... The `freemarkerConfiguration` must not be modified in `sendTemplatedEmail`. Like any other singleton bean, it should be fully configured during application startup.